# How do I get a bank account for political party?

Tags: united-kingdom

We created a political party in UK. And now we need a bank account in its name. What are the banks that have political party type account? Or will a business account do the job?

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please take a moment for our [tour]. This does not look to be on topic, consult our [help/on-topic] for a better picture of what you can ask about.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt I think it is a constructive subjective question about which a long enough answer can be written.

Comment: have you asked your own personal bank about it ?

Comment: @Max Nope. I need a bank account for party, and I need to know the right procedure for that in UK.

Comment: Other than asking your bank about it, ask the UK electoral commission https://www.electoralcommission.org.uk/

Comment: @user8262214 Could you explain what you mean by "political party type account"? By most metrics a UK political party is just a membership 'club', which might be registered with the Electoral Commission if people want to stand for elections in its name

Comment: For any legal persona (corporations, clubs, ngos) to operate you should first register it with the appropiate authority, which will then provide you with the documentation needed to perform its activities (among them opening bank accounts). If you just meet with some people and want to call it "a political party" that is ok, but legally that party does not exist and therefore it cannot be a part of a contract.

Comment: @SJuan76 Is that a statement of UK law? It certainly used to be the case that small organisations didn't always need to register, qv. eg. http://www.smallcharities.org.uk/starting-new-charity-faqs/#c5230 for charities.

Comment: This does not appear to be about "governments, policies and political process". It is not clear that the OP has "done his homework" (by, for example visiting a bank). Nobody here can give a definitive answer since we are not bank managers sitting with a prospective client.

Comment: I think this is more about how bank account creation works, maybe try: https://money.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done banking in the UK for charities and sports clubs. Any high street bank will have some type of account for such organisations, which is likely to be appropriate for a new political party. It may be known as a club account, community account, treasurer's account, or something else. Here are some general advice pages for the UK:

- [Scout out a good bank for your club](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/finance/personalfinance/bank-accounts/10095632/Scout-out-a-good-bank-for-your-club.html) (Daily Telegraph)
- [Bank accounts for community groups](http://www.resourcecentre.org.uk/information/bank-accounts-for-community-and-voluntary-organisations/) (ResourceCentre)

If your party becomes particularly large and successful, its financial affairs will become more complicated; but this is something you can discuss with your bank if and when it happens.

Your party will of course need to comply with relevant laws on political parties and election funding, but the bank is unlikely to have any responsibility for this. (As an analogy: If you were running a charity, it wouldn't really be the bank's job to check if you were handling money in accordance with the legal requirements for charitable status.)

Answer (score 2):

Political parties usually (always?) are considered non-profits, so whatever legislation applies to non-profits applies to your new party.

You basically need to show up at your bank and open an account like you would for any other business, the difference being that you're a non-profit rather than a for-profit organization.

Comment: FYI, "non-profit" and "for-profit" are US terms which are not really used in the UK.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure there is a special type of account for political parties (it might operate as one for a company), but there are certain rules that might pop in when opening an account or after its creation:

- [special reports for Electoral Commission](https://www.electoralcommission.org.uk/find-information-by-subject/political-parties-campaigning-and-donations/political-parties-annual-accounts)

> All party headquarters, and those accounting units with income or
>   spending of over £25,000, have to send us annual statements of their
>   accounts. We publish parties’ statements of accounts online to ensure
>   there is transparency about their income and spending.

- [bank can close the account(s)](http://www.financial-ombudsman.org.uk/publications/ombudsman-news/48/banking-closing-accounts.htm) under certain conditions

> [...]Like most other commercial
>   organisations, banks and building societies are under no obligation to
>   continue doing business with someone if they do not consider it
>   appropriate to do so.

E.g.: [Barclays Bank bans BNP accounts](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/business/3901621.stm)

It would be interesting to know if any of the criteria or extra checking applied to [politically exposed persons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politically_exposed_person#UK) apply in this case (could not find information about this).

Comment: The Politically Exposed Person thing is interesting, but I'm 99.9% certain the OP is *not* already a member of the UK Parliament. Just being a parliamentary candidate is not enough to make you a PEP.